# PowerApps AzureBlobStorage ListFolderV2 Only Returning 324 Blobs

Tags: azure-blob-storage, powerapps

An AzureBlobStorage connector is being used in an existing PowerApp. Around last week, the ListFolderV2 action is only returning 324 blobs out of more than 3,000 blobs in the container. I tried using ListFolderV4 instead, and specified {useFlatListing:true}, but the same amount was returned.

Answer (score 1):

> In some cases, When a blob is added or modified (properties only)
> trigger may delay in returning blobs immediately and postpone newly
> created/modified blobs for the next trigger runs. This means that the
> trigger does not guarantee to return all files in a single run when
> "Split On" option is disabled.

Refer  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#known-issues-and-limitations) for known issues and limitations and check if any of it is your case.

[image]

Or

Try by adding [Azure Blob Storage nextPageNumber](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Azure-Blob-Storage-nextPageNumber/m-p/545607#M167761) parameter to collect blobs in parts or pieces and merge them finally (See the solution part).

**References:**

1. [azureblob/actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#actions)
2. [Connect to azure Blob storage from power apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-azure-blob-storage#download-files-from-azure-blob-storage)